# How can change ColumnName of table with for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

```
x = [];
x = ['A':'Z'];
for i='A':'Z'
    for j='A':'Z'
        x = [cellstr(x),[i,j]];
    end
end
for i=1:100
    app.UITable.ColumnName ={x(i)};
end
```

I want to change `ColumnNames` with x characters but it doesn't work with above code. Hhow can I solve this  problem?

Comment: Why set them in a loop, and not all at once: `app.UITable.ColumnName = x(1:100);`

Comment: thanks it worked,I am begginer and I am writing an excel project with matlab app designer for school,can I ask my problems from you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename only in a special index you can use

```
app.UITable.ColumnName =x(i+1);
```

if you want to name all table columns in a for loop, you can use this script

```
x = [];
x = ['A':'Z'];
for i='A':'Z'
    for j='A':'Z'
        x = [cellstr(x),[i,j]];
    end
end
for i=1:100
    app.UITable.ColumnName{1,i} =x(i+1);
end
```